# XNA: Collisions between rotating sprites

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

Right now to do rotation I have a separate frame for each angle of rotation, but I much rather have one image that I rotate.  My question is, how do I do a matrix transformation in XNA/C# so the color data is also rotated the same way the sprite is rendered on the screen?  I found this old [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024248/implementing-per-pixel-collision-on-rotated-sprites), but I really don't understand the answer, and I'd like to know how the code works in case it needs to be modified later.

Any and all positional/rotational information needed is stored in the entity that contains the sprite, and both sprites are assumed to rotate.

Here is my code so far:

```
private static bool PixelPerfect(PhysicsEntity a, PhysicsEntity b)
    {
        if (!BoundingBox(a, b)) return false;

        var colorDataA = new Color[a.Sprite.Source.Width * a.Sprite.Source.Height];
        var colorDataB = new Color[b.Sprite.Source.Width * b.Sprite.Source.Height];

        a.Sprite.Texture.GetData(0, a.Sprite.Source, colorDataA, 0, colorDataA.Length);
        b.Sprite.Texture.GetData(0, b.Sprite.Source, colorDataB, 0, colorDataB.Length);

        var top = (int) Math.Max(a.BoundingBox.Top, b.BoundingBox.Top);
        var bottom = (int) Math.Min(a.BoundingBox.Bottom, b.BoundingBox.Bottom);
        var left = (int) Math.Max(a.BoundingBox.Left, b.BoundingBox.Left);
        var right = (int) Math.Min(a.BoundingBox.Right, b.BoundingBox.Right);

        for (var y = top; y < bottom; y++)
        {
            for (var x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                var colorA = colorDataA[(int) ((y - a.BoundingBox.Top) * (a.BoundingBox.Width) + (x - a.BoundingBox.Left))];
                var colorB = colorDataB[(int) ((y - b.BoundingBox.Top) * (a.BoundingBox.Width) + (x - a.BoundingBox.Left))];
                if (colorA.A == 0 || colorB.A == 0) continue;
                a.CollisionPoint.ChangePositon(x, y);
                b.CollisionPoint.ChangePositon(x, y);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the data constant. You just modify the way you access it.

For pixel-perfect collision detection, the basic idea is as follows: You have two sprites that are rendered with transform matrices `m1` and `m2`, respectively. Now iterate every pixel of sprite 1. Find out what screen position this pixel is located at. Find out the pixel of sprite 2 that is located at the same (or similar) position.

The transform matrices are usually something like

```
t = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(angle) * Matrix.CreateTranslation(position);
```

You can check your matrix calculation with the overload of `SpriteBatch.Begin()` that takes a matrix.

The transformation from sprite 1's pixel space to world space is:

```
worldPos = sprite1LocalPos * m1
```

The transformation form world space to sprite 2's pixel space is:

```
sprite2LocalPos = worldPos * Matrix.Invert(m2)
                = sprite1LocalPos * m1 * Matrix.Invert(m2)
```

And this is basically all you need to do:

```
Matrix transform = m1 * Matrix.Invert(m2);
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, texture2.Width, texture2.Height);
for (int x = 0; x < texture1.Width; x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < texture1.Height; y++)       //Iterate every pixel of sprite 1
    {
        index = x + texture1.Width * y;             //Calculate the pixel index
        if (data1[index].A < 10)                    //If the pixel is (almost) transparent, 
            continue;                               //ignore it

        Vector2 sprite1Local = new Vector2(x, y);
        Vector2 sprite2Local                              //get the pixel of sprite 2 
            = Vector2.Transform(sprite1Local, transform); //that is at the same position

        if(!rect.Contains((int)sprite2Local.X, (int)sprite2Local.Y))
                                                    //if this is outside of the sprite, 
            continue;                               //ignore it

        index2 = (int)sprite2Local.X + (int)sprite2Local.Y * texture2.Width;
        if(data2[index2].A>10)                      //If the pixel is not transparent, 
            return true;                            //there is a collision
    }
}
return false;
```